# Using node 'fs' module and 'readdir' method using AMD

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, amd, readdir

I need to loop through a folder (the data folder in my application) and get file names in a javascript application. The application is not setup as a `Node.js` application per se ( although I have `npm` and `node.js` installed on my computer). It seems that the options to do this are limited. I am seeing either a `php` solution or a Node.JS solution using the `File-System` or `fs` module and the `.readdir` method. I have already run `>>npm install file-system --save' to install the module and create a`node-module` folder. However, my application is setup more AMD style to bring in modules and libraries like this:

```
require([...
    "dojo/json",
    "dojo/promise/all",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function(JSON,
    all) { ...
```

Can I just add `"/node-modules/file-system"` under my `require([..` and `file-system` in `function(...` and start using the methods? Is there something I am missing here or an easier way to do this?

Comment: "However, my application is setup more AMD style" — Where is your application running? Are you writing AMD style code to run on Node.js? Or are you trying to run code in a browser? (Or are you using something else like Windows Scripting Host or Adobe Photoshop?)

Comment: I was not trying to write AMD style code to run on Node.JS originally. Until I ran into the problem of not being able to iterate through a local folder anyway. This is a web application with GIS functionality written with generic javascript and pulling in some libraries and APIs (the ESRI ArcGIS API in particular) that made the AMD setup easier (based on the API documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing UI code, but what you want to do is access some items on the file system.

You won't be able to access files in the file system from the browser - you would need to have a node.js service layer (if you want to use node.js) that can send that information to the UI via HTTP requests. [Link about why JS does not have access to filesystem](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-html)

For a node.js service to do that,  those modules are already available without any installation of additional modules

```
// index.js 

var fs = require('fs');

// your logic here:
```

All you'd need to do to start that server side logic would be to run `node index.js`

Setting up a Web API goes a little beyond this post, but there are plenty of tutorials and frameworks and help for setting up a node.js server if you haven't done so before.

I'd recommend just trying it out with node.js since you already have it installed and experimenting a little bit to understand how it works.